# Serializing a derived class from an interface

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

**New:** Can I use this, from access.hpp?

```
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void serialize_adl(Archive &, T &, const unsigned int);
```

This suggests that I can define a different serialize that takes the object as a parameter.

Thus would this code change below work?

I think my question is how do I add a serialize method on an
interface class, which will invoke the serialize method on the
derived sub-class.

```
class Interface {
public:
    virtual void aVirtual() = 0;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive, class T>
    void serialize_adl(Archive & ar, T & object, const unsigned int version)
    {
       // Would this work?????
       ar & object;
    }
};

template<class T>
class Derived : Interface {
public:
   Derived(T in) : m_data(in) {}
   virtual void aVirtual() { // Do something }
private:
    T m_data;
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
       ar & m_data;
    }
};
```

I currently get the following error from my compiler:

```
error C2039: 'serialize' : is not a member of 'Interface'
```

which is unusual because the object is inside a smart pointer, so it should
know what type it is:

```
std::unique_ptr<Interface> object = std::unique_ptr<Interface>(new Derived<int>(5));
```

And thus when I try to serialise:

```
archive >> *object;
```

Thus I get the error.

Comment: In this case, I would add another virtual method similar to `virtual void serializeImpl(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {}` to the interface class that's protected.  That way the serialize() on the interface can call serializeImpl() to get the derived functionality.

Comment: @ChrisCooper Yeah, this is a good use case of: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Comment: That will not work. The Archive in this case is a template. You cannot define a pure virtual function on the interface class, which takes a template parameter as an argument.

Comment: What would happen if I added the following to the Interface serialize method: ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Derived>(*this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two issues at play here:

1. You are serializing a template class. This is not a problem and yes you can do this  intrusively (member `serialize`) or non-intrusively (free function `serialize` via ADL). As the documentation ([Serializing Templates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#templates)) states the implementation of `shared_ptr<T>` serialization is a good example of the non-intrusive variant here:

   - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp
2. You are serializing base/derived classes through a polymorphic pointer. For the serialization part this is nothing special (you can `register_type` or you should be fine using `base_object<Interface>(this)` inside the derived's `serialize` function.

   On the deserialization side of things, however, you need to anticipate the full list of possible concrete instance types serialized through the polymorphic pointer. The `BOOST_EXPORT_CLASS` macro is the easiest way to achieve this. You will have to list the concrete instances of the template you wish to support, though:

   ```
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<std::string>)
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<double>)
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<int>) // include all subtypes we can expect in an input archive
   ```

   or

   ```
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Derived<std::string>, "4ef5a3ff-168a-4242-846b-4886f48424b5")
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Derived<double>,      "d0ed9de6-584f-476d-9898-8234bcb4efdb")
   BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Derived<int>,         "505538f0-2dd1-43bd-92a2-506ed9659bbe") // include all subtypes we can expect in an input archive
   ```

The complexity of the situation - and the confusion - arises from the fact that you are serializing a *derived* class template through a polymorphic pointer. All at the same time. But conceptually both are easily tackled.

> Slightly unrelated,
>
> - Yes, you can use free function serialize, see the 3rd alternative version below. It gains you little though, and just requires `m_data` to be publicly accessible.
> - *Do not use `serialize_adl` as it is an implementation detail*

Here are three samples that integrates everything:

1. **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/133a69b913829887)</kbd>** - raw `Interface*`
2. **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46f2aaa8851247d1)</kbd>** - same with `shared_ptr<Interface>`
3. **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaaa4320416210e5)</kbd>** - same with non-intrusive `serialize` function

### Listing for the first sample

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <sstream>

class Interface {
    public:
        virtual void aVirtual() = 0;
        virtual ~Interface() {}
    private:
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive&, unsigned) { }
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Interface)

template<class T>
class Derived : public Interface {
    public:
        Derived(T in = 0) : m_data(in) {}
        virtual void aVirtual() { /*Do something*/ }
        T const& getData() const { return m_data; }
    private:
        T m_data;
        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned)
            {
                ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Interface>(*this);
                //// alternatively, if you don't want to make the abstract base serializable:
                // boost::serialization::void_cast_register<Derived, Interface>();

                ar & m_data;
            }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<std::string>)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<double>)
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(Derived<int>) // include all subtypes we can expect in an input archive

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss);

        Interface* o = new Derived<int>(42);
        oa << o;

        delete o;
    }

    std::cout << "Serialized: '" << ss.str() << "'\n";

    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss);

        Interface* o = nullptr;
        ia >> o;

        if (auto p = dynamic_cast<Derived<int>*>(o))
            std::cout << "Deserialized into Derived<int> with data: " << p->getData() << "\n";

        delete o;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Serialized: '22 serialization::archive 11 0 1 1 12 Derived<int> 1 0
0 42
'
Deserialized into Derived<int> with data: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe this could help you or i could be wrong; but in c++ inherit, There is not a mechanism for to make call to subclass's methods, because a class can to have many subclass and the superclass have not the subclass's reference, because the polymorphism function from subclass to superclass and not in mode inverse. for that reason, you can call a superclass's function since the derived class.

best regards.

Answer (score -1):

You should serialize only the derived object. use dynamic_cast for Type conversion

```
 class Interface { 
     virtual void f() = 0; 
 }; 

 template<class T> class Derived : public Interface {
     T m_data; void f(){}; 
 }; 

 Interface* object = new Derived<Type>();

 Derived<Type>* objectSer = dynamic_cast<Derived<Type>*>(object); 

 //serialization 
 std::ofstream ofs("filename"); 
 boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs); oa << *objectSer;
```

Comment: Could you please include an example about what you mean specifically?

Comment: simple example
class Interface
{
 virtual void f() = 0;
};
template<class T>
class Derived
{
 T m_data;
 void f(){};
};
Interface* object = new Derived<Type>();
Derived<Type>* objectSer = dynamic_cast<Derived<Type>*>(object);

Comment: Thanks you for bringing this overdue question to my attention. It still needed a proper answer.